# Packaging a Python app with PyPI + OS-level dependencies

Tags: python, packaging, pip, pypi

I would like to package a Python scientific application for PyPI. My problem is that it relies on PyPI-level deps (e.g. numpy, scipy, etc.) as well as others which must be dealt at the OS-level: wxPython and Python-VTK (e.g. with apt-get on Ubuntu, homebrew on OSX, etc).

I'd like to know what would be the ideal strategy for doing this, and in particular, which packaging system would fit best (I'm currently favoring Distribute).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`distribute` is a fork of `setuptools` with better perhaps documentation. You basically have `distutils` (stdlib) and `setuptools` as your choices. Since `distutils` doesn't let you specify dependencies, only `setuptools` is left.

You generally list all dependencies, and document the installation procedure clearly (including in the long_description field pushed to PyPI). Include the OS-level installed packages, most distributions include the egg information when installing these.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. Apart from listing and documenting the installation steps clearly, does setuptools provide some additional mechanism that could help in scripting the installation of the OS-level deps? If not, I wonder what would be the benefit of registering my package on PyPI at all (I mean, if it requires the user to perform extra manual steps, i.e. if it's not able to completely automate the process).

Comment: No, sorry. Neither setuptools nor the installation tools (pip, easy_install, zc.buildout) provide support for that. But, even for many eggs available on PyPI, you still need to install OS-level dependencies; cxOracle requires oracle drivers, PIL needs libjpeg and such, etc. Also, some of your dependencies are best installed by the os, but *can* be installed as eggs too. This is a hard problem to solve with tools only, so documentation is the better way to go.